# How to show message alongside some items which are at the end of the list with pagination?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

```js
currentPage: 1,
  perPage: 3,

  computed: {
    rows() {
      return this.productsList.length;
    },
    paginatedItems() {
      return this.productsList.slice(
        this.currentPage * this.perPage,
        (this.currentPage + 1) * this.perPage
      );
    },
  },
```

```html
<div class="overflow-auto">
  <div class="product-plp1" v-for="product in paginatedItems" :key="product.key" id="product" :items="productsList" :per-page="perPage" :current-page="currentPage">
  </div>
</div>
<b-pagination v-model="currentPage" :total-rows="rows" :per-page="perPage"></b-pagination>
```

How to show a message at last page of pagination if no available items  in Vuejs?

Basically i want to show message on screen when there is no available items in the pagination "Sorry no products"

For example if page number 8 is the last product items available then i need to show message there.

For that do i need to take a div tag and then i need to link it to pagination, But i am not sure how to start.

Comment: Why should there be a page when there is no items on the page? (unless it is the only page and no items exist)

Comment: @TJ I mean not a page, But need to show some messages like "you reached almost end like so...".   That message should appear at last pagination number if no items available.

Comment: So this message shows up alongside some items which are at the end of the list?

Comment: Yes that's what exactly.

Comment: @TJ as per below answer,  I am able to see ""no items left"" in each page of pagination. But wanted to show up alongside some items which are at the end of the list.

Can you please provide some input here, If possible. So that it could be very helpful to me.

Answer (score 0):

First and foremost, there should be no page if there is no products on this page.

Still, if you want to do this, here's how:

1. Check if any there are any items in your list, if so - display the list.
2. Check if there's no items in your list and display message.

```js
<template>
  <div>
    <div v-if="list.length">
      <div v-for="item in list" :key="item">{{ item }}</div>
    </div>
    <div v-if="!list.length">No items left</div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      list: [], // empty list indicates no items on the page
    };
  },
};
</script>
```

Also, some people prefer to use `v-else` ([docs](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#v-else)) instead of `v-if="!list.length"`

Comment: Thanks for answering :) befoe this  <div class="overflow-auto"> do i need to place ??
After placing there on each and every page it is showing "no items left"

Comment: Wherever you like it to be, but you have to also set `v-if` on your list - like in my example.

Comment: After replacing the above code, ""No items left"" is displaying on all the pages in the pagination. But need to  show up alongside some items which are at the end of the list.

Comment: Can you please provide some input here, If possible. So that it could be very helpful to me.